# Why CSS Modules styling is not working on my elements, RMWC?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am following the tutorial below on react material web components (RMWC) and got confused with the styling and theming chapters.

https://jamesmfriedman.github.io/rmwc/styling-theming

In this chapter, the author tries to explain differences between using standard CSS and CSS Modules, but I am unable to understand this. What are  the differences between the two and why do we use CSS modules and how is it different from standard CSS?

I am also trying to apply CSS using CSS modules, but CSS is not getting applied over the elements. Am I doing something wrong here?

I am using Create-React-App.

My code (style is not getting applied):

index.js

```
    import React from 'react'
    import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
    import styles from './index.css'

    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'

    class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                  <Button className={styles.button}>
                    CSS Modules
                  </Button>
                </div>
                )
        }
    }

    ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

index.css

```
    .button {
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fe6b8b 30%, #ff8e53 90%);
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 0;
      color: white;
      height: 48px;
      padding: 0 30px;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3);
    }
```

Even though by doing it in below way , it is working fine.

```
    import React from 'react'
    import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
    import styles from './index.css'

    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'

    class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                  <Button className="button">
                    CSS Modules
                  </Button>
                </div>
                )
        }
    }

    ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: 1. You can find detailed differences between standard CSS and CSS Modules through a quick Google search, and 2. You need to show your code for us to determine why your styles aren't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine except for one small detail you might have missed. Using `create-react-app` allows you to use css modules if you follow [their guidelines](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet). Your file name needs to be `index.module.css` for it to work as a css module.

Reference:

> This project supports CSS Modules alongside regular stylesheets using the [name].module.css file naming convention.

Comment: Thank you. It worked like a charm. But still I am unable to get the difference b/w the two, using simple stylesheets and css modules.

Comment: @Sagar The main difference is that you can refer to css modules in a more programmatic way. On the same page I linked it says `CSS Modules let you use the same CSS class name in different files without worrying about naming clashes.`

Comment: but using same class names in different stylesheets will also work I think so

Comment: @Sagar no, the element that has the class will get style of different stylesheets. if the property is the same in two stylesheets, the element will get style of stylesheet that is included at last

Comment: @Sagar Not quite. As an example, if you were to have two stylesheets that you wanted to use in your app, and they had a conflict in their name, the last one to be imported would override the first one.

E.g. `styles.css` & `styles2.css` both have a class called `.button`. The second one would override the first

Comment: Author has explained CSS Modules styling examples in link https://jamesmfriedman.github.io/rmwc/styling-theming which is not working for me unless I update the styleesheet from  
                                                                                     
 myDrawerHeader :global(.mdc-drawer__header-content) {
    color: red;
} to simple myDrawerHeader. Why is it so?

Comment: @Sagar During the compile it automatically names your css styles with some unique identifiers, that's how it resolves conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about programming best practice, using global variable is bad.

Because you will run to collision of variable eventually. For worst case, there's no any warn and you're just confused when the value of variable is changed.

In css, sharing class or any selector might help you save time to write css. but eventually you will get some problem (especially in medium-large code base) finding that element is styled by unintentionally class or selector or you want to change style of some element but it affect other element that you don't want.

I suggest you reading this link for further detail.

https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/

for you case, you need to setup babel plugin to use css modules in react

https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules

if you create project by create-react-app, you should look at @Keno Clayton 's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer what different among standart css with css module, when you make more than one page. You will use some css to different page and sometimes you will use same css class name. Same class name will make css overwrite your style. CSS Module comes to fix that problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).